# In $q.all concept in AngularJs, what happens when one of the promises gives 404 Error

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services

I am calling multiple URLs iteratively and for each URL request, I am adding the returned promise into an array. After iteration, I am using `$q.all()`to get the results and add the data from all the requests into a single array.

My task is to **collect and store the data in an array until a URL returns no data**. But, as per `$q.all` implementation, I read that if one promise gives 404 error, then the whole batch of requests will be rejected. **How to overcome this** OR Any other ways to achieve my task?

```js
var calculateMutationsInDepth = function(){
   var depthRange=[0,1,2,3];
   var promises[]; // Promises array
                    //Calling GET request for each URL
   depthRange.foreach(function(depth){
                        var resourceUrl = urlService.buildSonarUrlsWithDept(depth);
   promises.push($http.get(resourceUrl));
      });
   
  //Resolving the promises array
   $q.all(promises).then(function(results){
    var metricData=[]; //Array for appending the data from all the requests
    results.forEach(function(data){
     metricData.push(data);
    })
    analyzeMutationData(metricData); //calling other function with collected data
    });
  };
```

Comment: error handler in your individual request? can you post your existing code?

Comment: @tymeJV : Please find the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$http.get(resourceUrl)
```

the above is a promise which is resolved to an HTTP response object if the request succeeds, and rejected to an HTTP response object if the request fails.

```
$http.get(resourceUrl).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
})
```

the above is a promise which is resolved to the body of an HTTP response object if the request succeeds, and still rejected to an HTTP response object if the request fails, since you haven't handled the error case

```
$http.get(resourceUrl).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
}).catch(function(response) {
    return null;
})
```

or

```
$http.get(resourceUrl).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
}, function(response) {
    return null;
})
```

the above is a promise which is resolved to the body of an HTTP response object if the request succeeds, and which is resolved to null if the request fails. It's never rejected, since you've handled the error.

So, if you use `$q.all()` with an array of such promises as argument, you'll have a promise which will always be resolved, to an array. The array elements will be the response bodies, or null for the requests which failed.

Comment: Can you also explain, how can I come out of the **foreach** loop (depthRange) _for the first time the response is null_ (When 404 Error is received for a URL request for the first time).

Comment: Don't use forEach. Use a good old for loop. I'm talking about the second for loop. You can't break out of the first one on this condition, since a this point, you don't have any response yet.

Comment: So in my first forEach, According to you, If my array is set of integers from 0 to 1000, Will it call the GET method 1000 times? Can't I terminate the loop whenever I don't get the data anymore?

Comment: No. An AJAX request is asynchronous, by definition. That's why you're dealing with promises in the first place. The whole loop creating the promises takes a few nanoseconds. Then, much later, when the responses come back, the functions passed to then() are executed.